# A question about the hierarchy of topologies on a given set

Tags: general-topology, big-list

It's easier to understand with examples:

- Every finer topology than a Hausdorff topology is hausdorff.
- Every coarser topology than a compact topology is compact.

What are the full set of properties which admit a statement of this kind?

Comment: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ams.org%2Ftran%2F1966-122-02%2FS0002-9947-1966-0190893-2%2FS0002-9947-1966-0190893-2.pdf&ei=JimbUpmaCuSl4AS1q4D4AQ&usg=AFQjCNGgAuEYXPSHkaM2hsOhNOSSUz91Xg&sig2=dSzdHk1a7r3N-nnKkiGnQw&bvm=bv.57155469,d.bGE 

This might be relevant.

Comment: Here's a start:- Any coarser topology than a connected one is connected
- Any finer topology than a $T_1$/$T_2$/$T_3$ topology is $T_1$/$T_2$/$T_3$ respectively. (This may be true for all separation axioms)

Comment: @ShaulBarkan: The [K-topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-topology) on the real line is finer than the usual (metric) topology, but is not regular (or completely regular, or normal, or ...).  (In this topology $F = \{ 1/n : n \geq 1 \}$ is a closed set not containing $0$, but $0$ and $F$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer I knew it! It was too easy, I became suspicious. Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A connected set remains connected in a coarser topology.

The boundary of a subset increases with coarser topologies and decreases with finer topologies.

Continuity is preserved by coarsening the image or refining the domain.